# Twitter Bootstrap css topbar html/css

Tags: html, css

I have this (using the Twitter bootstrap css sheet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style='padding-top:40px;'>

<div class='topbar'>
  <div class='fill'> 
      <a class='brand' href='index.php'>BrandTest</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's not showing the black bar at the top at the top.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of the HTML is missing, it should look like this : http://jsfiddle.net/KajxK/

```
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="topbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="index.php">BrandTest</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```