# Twitter Bootstrap HAML topbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a topbar using twitter bootstrap, but the black bar won't render. I've got a simple rails app with `haml-rails` and `less-rails-bootstrap`.

I tried the following haml:

```
!!! 5
%html
   = render 'layouts/header'
   %body
     .topbar-wrapper
       .topbar
         .topbar-inner
           .container
             %a{:href => "brand", :href=>"#"} Name
     .container
       = yield
```

I had a look on SO and found the following post: [Twitter Bootstrap css topbar html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346290/twitter-bootstrap-css-topbar-html-css) I tried translating that HTML into haml, but this doesn't work either:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %body
    .topbar
      .topbar-inner
        .container
          %a{:class => "brand", :href =>"#"} Name
```

I can see the bootstrap styling, so I have included bootstrap and it is being rendered along with the page. I must be making some mistake in my haml.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? 1.4 or 2.0?

Comment: 2.0, from gem less-rails-bootstrap 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML scaffold in Bootstrap 2.0 is different from the one proposed in 1.4:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In HAML this would be something like:

```
.navbar
  .navbar-inner
    .container
       ...
```

You can find more details at: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: I'm getting a better result using this but it's still not quite right, there is no black bar. I'm not overriding the styling anywhere else, am I missing something?

Comment: Whoops, I had written 'narbar' instead of 'navbar'.